# Changing the appearance of a checkbox field in iText

Tags: java, itext

I need to be able to customize the checkbox fill type on demand as I render the pdf.

I must do this only with the **AcroFields** (pdfStamper.getAcroFields()), because I'm not creating any new fields (just modifying), and that's the only thing I have available to me in scope. I have tried about a hundred things, including the one listed below, which was my best guess on how to do this.

```
  PdfDictionary dictionary = (PdfDictionary)  acrofields.getFieldItem("ABCD").getWidget(0).get(PdfName.MK);
  dictionary.put(PdfName.CA, new PdfString("8", PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));
```

ABCD is just for testing.

I am very stuck, and any help would be greatly appreciated. I am able to change the value in the dictionary, but it does not seem to have any affect when I write the pdf to a file. Other changes such as setting the checkbox to being checked/unchecked work, as well as populating text fields. So I as very surprised and confused why this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to change the caption of a check box, but it's unclear to me what you expect to see. Do you want to see the text "8"? In that case, changing the caption isn't sufficient. You also need to change the appearance. You can find the possible appearances under the `/AP` key. In the case of a check box, you'll find two possible appearance states under the normal appearance (`/N`). These XObjects define what you see when the PDF is rendered.

Comment: I'm trying to change the fill type from a check mark or X to a star.

Comment: OK, the check mark is defined in the "on" state of the appearances. You need to replace that "on" state. Merely changing the CA value isn't sufficient.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much, but if it's ok can you please give an example of how I would do this (change the fill appearance, let's say from a checkmark to a star), and what values to use.

Comment: I have too much work to do that right now. Why don't you give a shot at it first? Also: *what values to use?* seems like you didn't really understand my answer, so why don't you take a look at your PDF using iText RUPS? You'll have a better understanding of what's needed.